# Why do I get no instance of constructor matches argument list for code below in different files?

Tags: c++, class

The client function

```
void main()
{
    using namespace std;
    double a = 4.0;
    double b = 5;
    COMPLEX::Complex cmplxone(4.0,5.0);
}
```

Complex Class

```
#ifndef Complex_HEADER_H_
#define Complex_HEADER_H_

#include <iostream>

namespace COMPLEX
{
    class Complex
    {
    public:
          enum MODE { RECT, POLAR };
    private:
//object consists of four parts
            double realpart; //user enters this either rectangular or polar
            double imaginarypart; //user enters this either rectangular or polar
            double angle;
            double magnitude;
            MODE mode;
//private functions
            void setangle(); 
            void setmag();
//          Complex topolar() const;
//          void torectangular();
//public functions
    public:
            Complex(); //Default constructor
            Complex(double, double, MODE);
```

My Complex non-default constructor has 3 arguments.

When I define an object: cmplxone(4.0,5.0) it says no instance of constructor matches argument list for the first argument.

Comment: I was planning to omit the third argument, and built a method where if the argument is ommited defaults to a particular value in the constructor definition. Is that not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor only has 3 arguments, you have only specified 2.

You must either create a new constructor that takes 2 arguments or add a third argument into your method call.

--Edit--

You could make the third argument nullable, then if the argument is null use the default value else use the argument.

Another solution is to create a new constructor that takes the two doubles and inside that constructor create and set the default value.